# Entering data in a new column in excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, python-3.5, xls

I'm using Python 3.5.2

This is my input:

```
print("")
print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("|      (1) Enter new student details        |              (2) Edit existing student details           |           (3) Retrieve Student details            |")
print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("")
option=int(input("Select an option from the menu, 1/2/3/: "))
if option==1:
    f=open("Student Details.xls" , "w")
    f.write("Forename"+"\n")
    fname=input("Enter the student's first name: ")
    f.write(fname)
    f.write("Surname"+"\n")
    sname=input("Enter the student's surname: ")
    f.write(sname)
    f.write("DOB"+"\n")
    dob=input("Enter the student's DOB: ")
    f.write(dob)
    f.write("Postcode"+"\n")
    pcode=input("Enter the student's postcode: ")
    f.write(pcode)
```

When this is run, it creates an excel file and write to it. But, it write all the details in one cell. I want the excel file to look like this:

```
Forename  Surname   DOB        Postcode
Jim       Bob       12/12/12   w7 1eu
```

I researched how to enter data in different columns, but all the solutions I found use the import xlwt, which I am unable to install - as I don't have admin permission on this PC.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: If you want to put them in adjacent columns, appending `\n` probably isn't the best way...

Comment: @Coldspeed How else should I approach this?

Comment: @Coldspeed xlrd is not inbuilt in this version of python

Comment: You can use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library.

Comment: @Coldspeed Could you write up an example please? I've read up on the documentation, but the code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: While you seem to be content to use `csv` from the standard library, you actually *can* use other packages. You don't need administrator access. You can simply unpack them into the same directory as your own source code that you are writing yourself. Then you can import them as though you wrote them yourself. (But if you do this, don't use xlwt. Use XlsxWriter instead.)

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend using something like [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) instead of dealing with files directly. It makes the process a lot simpler:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42

# Rows can also be appended
ws.append([1, 2, 3])

# Python types will automatically be converted
import datetime
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()

# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: I can't install modules, so I am unable to do 'import Workbook'